# Hide a hovered element until mouse out with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

I don't believe this is possible with pure CSS, but I wanted to confirm.

I have two elements. One is ontop of the other. When the user hovers over the top element I want to hide it and allow pointer events to pass through to the bottom element. When the user stops hovering I want to re show that element.

I've generated an example below, but it flickers. This is obviously because the :hover effect toggles on/off every time the mouse moves due to pointer-events: none.

Is this possible to achieve without JavaScript?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
.container:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.box:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
</div>
<div class='box'>
</div>
```

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/q7mo5v1j/) what you want?

Comment: Heh. Realizing that my question needs a bit of embellishment. I can see why that would be a viable answer for what I asked. Give me a second to update with an example that more closely reflects my scenario.

Comment: OK. I've updated the post to reflect my scenario. I'm still interested in a solution. My architecture is slightly different than this contrived example which prevents putting box inside of container.

Comment: I think a possible solution could be change the elements in HTML, and then add the CSS: `.box:hover + .container { background-color: blue; }`. Check a [new demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/q7mo5v1j/1/). Otherwise I think it's not possible :(

Comment: Word :) Not a bad solution, but not fitting for my purposes. I'm just going do a getBoundingClientRect + bind a listener to window's mousemove, throttle it, and check coordinates. Ugly, but it'll do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want display: none or visibility:hidden, unless I am oversimplifying things drastically.

Comment: visibility: hidden will not allow the pointer events to pass down to the red box below it since the box model is preserved. display: none will exhibit the same effect as pointer-events: none because the element can't be hovered if it's box model isn't being respected.

Comment: I figured. Is display:none not the answer? I mean, I've built similar layouts before and I never even gave thought to JavaScript.

Comment: Ahh yeah. I went ahead and updated the post to more closely reflect my scenario. Box has to be outside of container. Container actually contains a list of items which have :hover effects and I'm trying to display .box in the corner, above all of them, and hide the box so the user can hover over the items if need be.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this open for a while just in case, but I don't believe what I need is possible to achieve with just CSS.

My solution is:

- Call `getBoundingClientRect` on `.box`
- Bind an event handler to the window's mousemove event.
- Throttle it for perf.
- Check the coordinates of the mouse and determine whether they're over `.box` and set state as appropriate.

It's ugly, but it'll do!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the answers and the comments so far, I'm led to believe the OP wants something like this?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
.container:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}
.behind {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.behind:hover .box{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
   <div class='behind'>
     <ul>
       <li>Massively long text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</li>
       <li>Massively long text 2 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</li>
     </ul>
     <div class='box'>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The only problem is that the pointer events aren't directly on the `.container` div, but a click should bubble up from `.behind` div, unless you want to hide buttons underneath the `.box` div, in which case you could place the buttons on the `.behind` div instead if that suffices?
It would help if there was more info on what the OP wants within the `.container` div and what mouse events would need to be triggered on it.